# Nuxt 3 - Client Side plugin with Vue Toast Notification

Tags: typescript, nuxt.js, vuejs3, toast, nuxtjs3

I've some trouble with Nuxt 3 client side plugin.

Nuxt 3 documentation for plugins says this:

> Nuxt will automatically read the files in your plugins directory and load them. You can use .server or .client suffix in the file name to load a plugin only on the server or client side.

I've added a plugin with the name "toaster.client.ts" in which I use a Vue Toast Notification package that has methods like "info", "success", etc.
This is how I use it into my pages:

`const { $toast } = useNuxtApp(); $toast.success('It works');`

However, when I refresh the page I get the following error:

`Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'success')` 
I have to do this for it to work:

`if(process.client){ $toast.success('You did it!'); }`

How can I fix this please ?
I am using Nuxt 3 with Composition API(setup) and Typescript

Comment: Hey Hikari, can you post the contents of your toaster.client.ts plugin file?

Comment: @ddaannnnyy

`import { useToast } from 'vue-toast-notification';

export default defineNuxtPlugin(nuxtApp => {
    const toast = useToast({
        position: 'top-right'
    });
    return {
        provide: {
            toast,
        }
    }
})`

Comment: It's good now

I forgot to use it into a lifecycle hook.
Btw, this is the stackblitz link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-uzjusu?file=pages%2Findex.vue

Answer (score 0):

It's good now!

I forgot to use it in a lifecycle hook.

By the way, this is the stackblitz link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-uzjusu?file=pages%2Findex.vue